# Ionic Google Maps Capacitor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, maps

Can I use this Ionic Google Maps plug-in with capacitor( https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc ) ? I Try

npm install cordova-plugin-googlemaps
npm install @ionic-native/googlemaps

But without success. How I install it with capacitor ? And how I get the current position ? I'm using Angular.

I need use it because the native Geolocation does't work with old Android versions.

Answer (score 3):

Specific for **Capacitor**, google maps works perfectly.

I would suggest you follow this [tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-google-maps-geolocation-geocoder-application/#.Xvg-ImozaCg). You can ignore the nativegeocoder implementation in the tutorial if you don't need it.

The above tutorial is based on including the javascript api in your index.html file and then referencing it in your code.

Works perfectly with all the functionalities mentioned in the google javascript docs.

There are two ways of implementing google maps in an ionic capacitor app.

1. Using a cordova plugin (which integrates google maps native SDK)
2. Using the google maps javascript API

[Read this article to understand the difference](https://www.joshmorony.com/google-maps-in-ionic-2-native-or-web/)

[Another tutorial for implementing google maps](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-google-maps-and-geolocation-in-ionic-with-capacitor/)

Do not forget to put this after you import statements in your .ts file where you need to access the map.

> declare var google;

Once you have integrated it like it is done in the tutorial, for Google geolocation, add this..

```
this.googleGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
this.googleGeocoder.geocode({'location': latlng},(results,status)=>{
  if (status === 'OK') {
     // do your stuff
  }
})
```

Comment: I will try it! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped the package name, it is `@ionic-native/google-maps`, not `@ionic-native/googlemaps`. Also, if you are using `@ionic-native/google-maps`, you don't need to install the other package.

For installation, first you must [create Google Maps API keys.](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/api_key/generate_api_key.md)

Then, run:

```
npm install @ionic-native/core@beta @ionic-native/google-maps@beta

ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..."
```

replacing the `...`s with your API keys.

Regarding getting the current position, you need to use `LocationService.getMyLocation()` to get the current location. [Here](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.6.0/class/locationservice/getMyLocation/README.md) is the documentation and a tutorial.

Comment: Yes it will. The question asks about Andriod, and `cordova-pluigin-googlemaps` will work on Andriod, according to the [known incompatible plugins list](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins).

Comment: Can I use the command "ionic cordova plugin add " in a Capacitor project ? The exemplo show how implements on Index.html, can you show an exemplo on page.ts ?

Comment: you cannot use "ionic cordova plugin add" command in a capacitor project..
You will have to use "npm i <plugin>"
and then, you will have to define the api key in your strings.xml file in native android..

Comment: you can not use ionic cordova plugin add from capacitor project

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is by using Google Maps JavaScript API.

Add this to **index.html**.Replace with your own API key.

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

In map **component.html**

```
<div class="map-div" #gmap></div>
```

Load the map In map **component.ts**

```
    @ViewChild('gmap') gmap!: ElementRef;

    myMap: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.loadMap()
    }

    public loadMap() {
      let mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7833, -122.4167), // Initial camera center of the map
        zoom: 12, //Camera zoom value
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, //Select the Google Map Type 
        disableDefaultUI: true //Disabled the default layout which contains zoom in and out buttons
      }

      this.myMap = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, mapOptions);//'gmap' is the html element 

      //Adding a marker
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: 35.7833, lng: -120.4167 }, //Latitude and longitude of the marker
        map: this.myMap
      });
    }

  }
```

Also you can find the full code on my Medium.com article [here](https://medium.com/@kodikaramalith/how-to-use-google-maps-api-in-ionic-angular-14-app-2b79cd8304a4)