# Google Map rendering on laptop but not on mobile in Ionic app

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to display Google Maps in my Ionic app & center on my current location.

When I run this on my laptop, it displays as expected.

But when I try to run it on my mobile device, the map isn't rendering.

Here is the code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.locateUser();
    console.log('My Coords', this.coordinates);
    this.getGoogleMaps().then(googleMaps => {
      const mapEl = this.mapElementRef.nativeElement;
      const map = new googleMaps.Map(mapEl, {
        center: this.coordinates,
        zoom: 16
      });
      googleMaps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', () => {
        this.renderer.addClass(mapEl, 'visible');
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Google Maps error:', err);
    });
  }

  private getGoogleMaps() {

    const win = window as any;
    const googleModule = win.google;

    if (googleModule && googleModule.maps) {
      return Promise.resolve(googleModule.maps);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myAPIKey';
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.onload = () => {
        const loadedGoogleModule = win.google;
        if (loadedGoogleModule && loadedGoogleModule.maps) {
          resolve(loadedGoogleModule.maps);
        } else {
          reject('Google Maps SDK not available.');
        }
      };
    });
  }

  private locateUser() {
    if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Geolocation')) {
      this.showErrorAlert();
      return;
    }

    Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then(geoPosition => {
        this.coordinates = {
          lat: geoPosition.coords.latitude,
          lng: geoPosition.coords.longitude
        };
        console.log(this.coordinates);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.showErrorAlert();
      });
  }
```

Can someone please tell me why this is working on my laptop, but not on my mobile?

Also, here are the steps I'm taking to run on the mobile:

- `ionic build`
- `ionic capacitor run android`
- Then I run the app in Android Studio.

Comment: I have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62619283/5379936
Follow the tutorial mentioned there.. google maps will work perfectly..

Comment: Are you getting any error on mobile? How are you debugging your app when you are running it on mobile?